# Not able to use the HERE Network Positioning v2 API (while v1 is working)

Tags: here-api, positioning

I am able to use the HERE Network Positioning API v1 successfully using [https://pos.ls.hereapi.com/positioning/v1/locate/?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://pos.ls.hereapi.com/positioning/v1/locate/?apiKey=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D) on Postman.

But, with the same API key and same body, the v2 API ([https://positioning.hereapi.com/v2/locate?apiKey={YOUR_API_KEY}](https://positioning.hereapi.com/v2/locate?apiKey=%7BYOUR_API_KEY%7D)) replies "These credentials do not authorize access".

As the v1 API is marked as "In maintenance" I would prefer to use v2 API.
What should I do?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: we've tested it using API_Key or AccessToken, either way works fine.
https://positioning.hereapi.com/v2/locate?apiKey=??
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
Could you please let us know what plan do you have ? You can check in on developer.here.com (on the left.)
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/000DF.png

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have this : "Project Plan: Freemium"

Comment: Hi Julien, sry about late reply. We checked you app plan, it looks fine. We will dig more to see why you are having the problem and get back to you as soon as I can.

Comment: Hi Julien, it seems freemium accounts work fine with V1 and V2. One thing you can do is that creating another account on developer.here.com so it doesn't block you. Could you also provide your current APP_ID to us? thanks

Comment: Hi, here is my current APP_ID: rTo9lUjnSUifvP0NDKeS.

Comment: It looks like the v2 API is now working on my account. No idea why... Will close this ticket